# How to use NetLogo to find a quartile or quintile?

Tags: netlogo

So I have a set of values and need to find the lowest or higher quartile. I know there is a function for finding a median value but what is the best way to go deeper?

Answer (score 1):

How many values do you have? If there's not too many, you can write your own function. That's what I have done below. It sorts the values then counts along the relevant percentage and reports back, interpolating if necessary. The code is a complete model so you can try it out.

```
turtles-own [test-value]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 150 [set test-value random-float 1]
  type "20%ile is " print calc-pct 20 [test-value] of turtles
end

to-report calc-pct [ #pct #vals ]
  let #listvals sort #vals
  let #pct-position #pct / 100 * length #vals
  ; find the ranks and values on either side of the desired percentile
  let #low-rank floor #pct-position
  let #low-val item #low-rank #listvals
  let #high-rank ceiling #pct-position
  let #high-val item #high-rank #listvals
  ; interpolate
  ifelse #high-rank = #low-rank
  [ report #low-val ]
  [ report #low-val + ((#pct-position - #low-rank) / (#high-rank - #low-rank)) * (#high-val - #low-val) ]
end
```

This will be slow if you have lots of values though. In that case, you may be better off using the `R` extension and calculating in R.